# Help me understand a decreasing function

Tags: functions

I'm trying to show that $f=\frac{1}{x^2 - 1}$ is decreasing in $[0,1[$ . By definition $f$ is decreasing there if $$f'(x) < 0,\forall x \in [0,1[$$

Differentiating $f$ with respect to $x$ yields $$f'(x)=\frac{-2x}{(x^2-1)^2}$$

And now $f'(x)<0$, when $0<x<1$, therefore $f$ is decreasing in $[0,1[$. What confuses me is that $f'(0)=0$, and not $<0$. Shouldn't this mean that $f$ is not decreasing in $[0,1[$? Or is it because $f'=0$ only at $x=0$ that it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $f'(x)\le 0$ for any $x\in[a,b]$ is a sufficient to guarantee that $f(x)$ is decreasing.

Moreover if $f'(x_0)=0$ only for $x_0\in[a,b]$ isolated then $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing.

Let consider for example $f(x)=-x^3$ with $f'(0)=0$ which is strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is continuous on  $[0,1]$ and decreasing on $(0,1]$ then it is automatically decreasing on $[0,1]$. By the way $f'(x) <0$ is only a sufficient condition for $f$ to be decreasing. **It is not the definition**.

Definition: $f$ is decreasing if $x <y$ implies $f(x) <f(y)$.